# How to tune GaussianNB?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, naivebayes

Trying to fit data with [`GaussianNB()`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.naive_bayes.GaussianNB.html#sklearn.naive_bayes.GaussianNB) gives me low accuracy score.

I'd like to try Grid Search, but it seems that parameters `sigma` and `theta` cannot be set. Is there anyway to tune `GausssianNB`?

Comment: Naive Bayes makes very strong independence assumptions. It'd probably move on to a more powerful model instead of trying to tune NB.

Comment: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/model_selection/randomized_search.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-model-selection-randomized-search-py should give you good idea how to use custom grid for CV based model tuning.

Comment: `GridSearchCV` tunes parameters, but `GuassianNB` does not accept parameters, except `priors` parameter.

Comment: Actually `GuassianNB` does not accept any parameter: `GaussianNB().get_params().keys()` results in empty dict.

Comment: Finally it seems that only way to make this model better is to preprocess data. `sigma_` and `theta_` returned by the `fit()`, should help

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can tune '**var_smoothing**' parameter like this:

```
nb_classifier = GaussianNB()

params_NB = {'var_smoothing': np.logspace(0,-9, num=100)}
gs_NB = GridSearchCV(estimator=nb_classifier, 
                 param_grid=params_NB, 
                 cv=cv_method,   # use any cross validation technique 
                 verbose=1, 
                 scoring='accuracy') 
gs_NB.fit(x_train, y_train)

gs_NB.best_params_
```

Answer (score 4):

As of [version 0.20](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.naive_bayes.GaussianNB.html)

`GaussianNB().get_params().keys()`
returns 'priors' and 'var_smoothing'

A grid search would look like:

```
pipeline = Pipeline([
    ('clf', GaussianNB())
])

parameters = {
    'clf__priors': [None],
    'clf__var_smoothing': [0.00000001, 0.000000001, 0.00000001]
}

cv = GridSearchCV(pipeline, param_grid=parameters)

cv.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_pred_gnb = cv.predict(X_test)
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with how GridSearchCV works but why did you name the properties of the parameters with the prefix 'clf__' is this required by GridSearchCV?

Comment: The pipeline here uses the classifier (clf) = GaussianNB(), and the resulting parameter 'clf__var_smoothing' will be used to fit using the three values above ([0.00000001, 0.000000001, 0.00000001]). Using GridSearchCV results in the best of these three values being chosen as GridSearchCV considers all parameter combinations when tuning the estimators' hyper-parameters. See documentation: [link](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/grid_search.html).

Answer (score 1):

In an sklearn pipeline it may look as follows:

```
pipe = Pipeline(steps=[
                    ('pca', PCA()),
                    ('estimator', GaussianNB()),
                    ])
    
parameters = {'estimator__var_smoothing': [1e-11, 1e-10, 1e-9]}
Bayes = GridSearchCV(pipe, parameters, scoring='accuracy', cv=10).fit(X_train, y_train)
print(Bayes.best_estimator_)
print('best score:')
print(Bayes.best_score_)
predictions = Bayes.best_estimator_.predict(X_test)
```

Answer (score -1):

Naive Bayes doesn't have any hyperparameters to tune.